# Red-Black Tree Deletion Partially Working

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I implemented a red black tree in c++ with find, insert and delete. The delete only works for right side nodes and for the root node. I can't figure out why it isn't working for any of the left side nodes. Here is my code:

```
Node* searchNode(Node* root, int value){
    Node* temp = root;
    while (temp != NULL){
        if (temp->val == value){
            return temp;
        }
        else if (temp->val < value){
            temp = temp->right;
        }
        else if (temp->val > value){
            temp = temp->left;
        }
    }
}

Node* sibling(Node* node){
    if ((node == NULL) || (node->parent == NULL)){
        return NULL;
    }
    if (node == node->parent->left){
        return node->parent->right;
    }
    else{
        return node->parent->left;
    }
}
Node* maxNode(Node* node){
    while (node->right != NULL){
        node = node->left;
    }
    return node;
}
void replaceNode(Node* old, Node* new_node){
    if (old->parent == NULL){
        old = new_node;
    }
    else{
        if (old == old->parent->left){
            old->parent->left = new_node;
        }
        else{
            old->parent->right = new_node;
        }
    }
    if (new_node != NULL){
        new_node->parent = old->parent;
    }
}
void deleteNode(Node* root, int value){

    Node* child;
    Node* temp = searchNode(root, value);
    if (temp == NULL){
        return;
    }
    if (temp->left != NULL&&temp->right != NULL){
        Node* pred = maxNode(temp->right);
        temp->val = pred->val;
        temp = pred;
    }
    if (temp->left == NULL || temp->right == NULL){
        if (temp->right == NULL && temp->left == NULL){
            child = temp;
        }
        else if (temp->right == NULL){
            child = temp->left;
        }
        else{
            child = temp->right;
        }
    }
        if (temp->color == 1){
            temp->color = child->color;
            delete_case1(root, child);
        }

        replaceNode(temp, child);
        delete temp;

}
void delete_case6(Node* root, Node* n)
{
    Node *s = sibling(n);

    s->color = n->parent->color;
    n->parent->color = 1;

    if (n == n->parent->left) {
        s->right->color = 1;
        rotate_left(root, n->parent);
    }
    else {
        s->left->color = 1;
        rotate_right(root, n->parent);
    }
}
void delete_case5(Node* root, Node* n)
{
    Node *s = sibling(n);

    if (s->color == 1) {
        if ((n == n->parent->left) &&(s->right->color == 1) &&(s->left->color == 0)) {
            s->color = 0;
            s->left->color = 1;
            rotate_right(root, s);
        }else if ((n == n->parent->right) &&(s->left->color == 1) &&(s->right->color == 0)) {
            s->color = 0;
            s->right->color = 1;
            rotate_left(root, s);
        }
    }
    delete_case6(root, n);
}
void delete_case4(Node* root, Node* n)
{
    Node *s = sibling(n);

        if ((n->parent->color == 0) && (s->color == 1) && (s->left->color == 1) && (s->right->color == 1)) {
            s->color = 0;
            n->parent->color = 1;
        }
        else{
            delete_case5(root, n);
        }

    }
void delete_case3(Node* root, Node* n){
    Node* s = sibling(n);
    if ((n->parent->color == 1) &&(s->color == 1) &&(s->left->color == 1) &&(s->right->color == 1)) {
        s->color = 0;
        delete_case1(root, n->parent);
    }
    else
        delete_case4(root, n);
}
void delete_case2(Node* root, Node* n){
    Node *s = sibling(n);
    if (s->color == 0){
        n->parent->color = 0;
        s->color = 1;
        if (n == n->parent->left){
            rotate_left(root, n->parent);
        }
        else if (n == n->parent->right){
            rotate_right(root, n->parent);
        }
    }
    delete_case3(root, n);
}
void delete_case1(Node* root,Node* n){
    if (n->parent != NULL){
        delete_case2(root,n);
    }
}



void main(){
    ABTree* ABtree=new ABTree;
    ABtree->root = NULL;
    insertTree(ABtree->root, 15);
    insertTree(ABtree->root, 8);
    insertTree(ABtree->root, 2);
    insertTree(ABtree->root, 9);
    insertTree(ABtree->root, 10);
    insertTree(ABtree->root, 12);
    insertTree(ABtree->root, 18);
    insertTree(ABtree->root, 25);
    insertTree(ABtree->root, 20);
    printTree(ABtree->root);
    Node* search=searchNode(ABtree->root, 18);
    cout << endl;
    cout << search->val<<endl;
    deleteNode(ABtree->root, 8);
    printTree(ABtree->root);
}
```

For example if i want to delete either 8/9/2 the program crashes at delete_case4 at the if statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I implemented once a red-black tree and it was hell. Create many test cases. Use an IDE which has a useful debugger, like Visual Studio. Then you can step through an see what happens. Write a method, which can print the tree out in some readable format. Print it out after each step.

Comment: Using Visual Studio with no much luck